# Cayley's formula question

Tags: graph-theory

I need help with wikipedia's explanation for the number of spanning trees in a complete graph.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence)
Can someone explain the sentence "The proof follows by observing that in the Prüfer sequence number $i$ appears exactly $(d_{i}-1)$ times." under the heading "Other applications"?
I don't see why.

Answer (score 1):

The formula given there $$\frac{(n-2)!}{(d_1-1)!(d_2-1)!\ldots (d_n-1)!}$$ is the number of sequences of length $n-2$ in which the number $i$ occurs $d_i-1$ times.  By the Prüfer correspondence, these sequences correspond 1-1 with labelled trees in which there are $i$ vertices of degree $d_i$, because in the algorithm that converts from labelled trees to Prüfer sequences, the vertices adjacent to a vertex $v$ of degree $d$ get removed one by one until $v$ becomes a leaf. Hence the label for $v$ gets written down $d-1$ times in the Prüfer sequence.

Comment: But WHY does the number i occur di times? I can't see the relationship between the number i and the degree.

Comment: Let $v_i$ be the vertex labelled $i$.  As you run through the algorithm, you remove all the vertices adjacent to $v_i$ (not necessarily in consecutive steps, of course) until finally $v_i$ becomes a leaf and you can remove $v_i$ itself.  Each time you remove a vertex adjacent to $v_i$, you write down the number $i$.  If $v_i$ has degree $d_i$, then you have to remove $d_i-1$ adjacent vertices before $v_i$ becomes a leaf, hence you will write down the number $i$ a total of $d_i-1$ times.  If this is not clear, run through the algorithm with some sample trees.

Comment: (Just made a correction in my answer, the value $i$ occurs $d_i-1$ times, not $d_i$.)

Comment: What happens if "the smallest label" is attached to multiple nodes? (eg. change the tree in the wiki article and make the label of vertex 4 to 1) Removing the that smallest label will remove not only the vertex with the smallest label but also all the vertices adjacent to the smallest label vertex. What do you write in the sequence then?

Comment: The algorithm chooses the smallest label *among leaves*, not the smallest label overall.  A leaf has only one neighbor.